# Reference Error {{variable}} is not defined at global in Rest Client in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, http

I try to use [Rest Client VS Code Extension from Huachao Mao](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client). I created a new profile in my workspace settings

**vs-code-workspace.code-workspace**

```json
{
    "settings": {
        "git.ignoreLimitWarning": true,
        "rest-client.enableTelemetry": false,
        "rest-client.environmentVariables": {
            "xyz": {
                "host": "http://localhost:8080/",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to send the following request

**request.http**

```
GET {{restBasePath}}/api/employee
```

but I'm getting

```js
ReferenceError: host is not defined at global.<anonymous> (c:\Users\dev\request.http:3:20) 
at N$ (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\anweber.vscode-httpyac-5.8.3\dist\extension.js:191:43412) 
at zCe (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\anweber.vscode-httpyac-5.8.3\dist\extension.js:191:43961) 
at c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\anweber.vscode-httpyac-5.8.3\dist\extension.js:191:47073 
at Jh (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\anweber.vscode-httpyac-5.8.3\dist\extension.js:190:30551) 
at Object.V3t [as action] (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\anweber.vscode-httpyac-5.8.3\dist\extension.js:191:47038) 
at I2e.<anonymous> (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\anweber.vscode-httpyac-5.8.3\dist\extension.js:1:5703) 
at Generator.next (<anonymous>) 
at s (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\anweber.vscode-httpyac-5.8.3\dist\extensi...
```

after I switched environment to `xyz` and tried to send the request. How to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed [vscode-rest-client](https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient) with [vscode-httpyac](http://httpyac.github.io/). httpyac is an alternative to vscode-rest-client developed by me (see httpyac.github.io). To configure my extension use setting httpyac.environmentVariables. To use vscode-rest-client use codelens Send Request. I would be happy for you to try httpyac, but I would recommend using only one of the two extensions and disabling the other.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, I wasn't aware of the latter extension